# Nullpointer exception on Flutter firebase data notification is receive and app is background

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter app that crashes with a null pointer when firebase data notification is received:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
> at androidx.core.content.a.checkSelfPermission(Unknown Source:41)
> at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.requestPermission(Unknown Source:22)
> at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(Unknown Source:376)
> at b9.k$a.a(Unknown Source:17)
> at p8.c.l(Unknown Source:18)
> at p8.c.m(Unknown Source:40)
> at p8.c.i(Unknown Source:0)
> at p8.b.run(Unknown Source:12)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

```
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

My flutter doctor

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.2, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559
> darwin-arm64, locale en-BG) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for
> Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2) [✓] Chrome - develop for
> the web [✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3) [✓] Android Studio
> (version 2021.1) [✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1) [✓] VS Code (version
> 1.64.2) [✓] Connected device (4 available) [✓] Network resources

My pubspec.yaml:

> firebase_core: ^2.9.0
> firebase_messaging: ^14.4.0

In my main, I call this extension function:

```
Future<void> _initMessaging() async {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((msg) => _firebaseMessagingHandler(msg));
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((msg) => _firebaseMessagingHandler(msg));
}
```

Handler looks like this

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingHandler(RemoteMessage msg) async => proceed(msg);
```

Comment: Did you allow permission for device and which verson of Android did you get that error ?

Comment: Yes, permissions are allowed, the error is received on SDK 33, but I tried with 29 and it is the same

Comment: check your code when set up Flutter Local Notification, this error is not related to FCM

Comment: The problem is when I send a data notification not push

Comment: So, you need find tutorial about how to use flutter local notification